# Refresh HTML5 page in Phonegap?

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, dreamweaver

I have got a fully working phonegap 1.6.1 application, built in HTML5. I'd like to make this page refresh itself from the internet (replace the in-app html file with the online one, and save it for later), but when it is not possible, just do nothing.

It is on Android (2.3.7 & 4.1.2)

Is it possible?

I would really appreciate if you could send me a code (script) that helps.

P. S. I'm doing the job in DreamWeaver without any databases, etc.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you wanting to replace the actual html with what is found on the corresponding web site or are you trying to update content on the page? One is possible the other is not as your html index is compiled into the adk and not really editable on the fly, per se. You may update content dymanically from the web, but I'm pretty sure it is impossible to re-compile your apk on the android device itself.

However, if your html file is nothing more than a web view or iframe of your web site, then it will work, provided the app may reach the internet. The problem is that your app will not work if not connected to the internet. However, you could write a js routine to pull a default html view when internet access cannot be had.

Comment: It is enough if I open it in browser, but the html has some specific links related to scripts in the application, and I fear that the HTML file would not be able to access them when on an other server, not compiled inside. If you could send me a tutorial on dynamic content for phonegap (which is A-Z), I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: By dynamic content, I mean AJAX. Your application would need to pull your code via AJAX and display a default view or error when unable to connect to your servers on the web.

Answer (score 1):

You need to whitelist your website in order for it to be allowed to take over the WebView provided by PhoneGap.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html

https://build.phonegap.com/blog/access-tags

Comment: Thank you, I will check the dynamic content, and in case of no success will I deal with this. But thank you anyway!